# CMD replace spaces with underscores

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have searched on this forum but not been able to recognize what I am looking for.
IRC dosen't allow the DCC of the files having spaces. How to create a batch file which replace spaces with underscore for all the MP3/FLAC files in the folder.
I tried this but failed

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern= "
Set "Replace=_"
For %%a in (*.mp3) Do (
Set "File=%%~a"
Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
Pause&Exit
```

It's giving me the error that the files are being used by another process though the files were not used by any programs and now it ain't doing anything whenever I run it it just says "press any key to continue and shuts down"

Any help?
thanks.

Comment: Try to change the `Set` line to `Set "File=%%~nxa"`, so only the file name is stored; then, change the `"%%a"` in the `Ren` line to `"%%~fa"` to provide the full path to the command; all this excludes any path-related trouble...

Answer (score 0):

Check with `echo` in front of `rename` command. It should works.

But if you are getting `the files are being used by another process`. This is certainly the case.

This can be an application blocked on closing, application hidden in systray, windows search indexer.
Restart or logoff computer may solve.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "pattern= "
set "replace=_"
for %%a in (*.mp3) do (
  set "file=%%~nxa"
  echo Ren "%%~fa" "!file:%pattern%=%replace%!"
  ::pause
)
pause
exit /b 0
```